# What is the difference between "real" and "present"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, differences

There is this sentence in the book called *The Uninhabitable Earth*.

> [W]e are likely to get about 3.2 degrees of warming, or about three times as much warming as the planet has seen since the beginning of industrialization—bringing the unthinkable collapse of the planet’s ice sheets ***not just into the realm of the real but into the present***.

In this context, what is the difference between "the realm of the real" and "[the realm of] the present"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The real*= something that could plausibly happen.

*The present* = something that is starting to happen now.